# saving dictionary into json python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am quite new to python and I was trying to make two arrays or matrices, register them into a dictionary, save to a json file. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import json
array_1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,6,7]])
array_2 = np.array([[4,0],[9,8]])
json_data = {
    'array_1': array_1,
    'array_2': array_2,
 }

import json

with open('json_data.json', 'wb') as fp:
    json.dumps(json_data, fp)
```

But I get the following error:

> Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Comment: The `json` module only knows how to serialize native Python types like `list`, `dict`, etc.  You will need to either store your arrays as Python `list`s in your `json_data` dictionary, or write a function that is called by `json.dumps` to do the conversion automatically. Read about the [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) parameter to `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 6):

First convert it to the python list like this:

```
json_data = {
    'array_1': array_1.tolist(),
    'array_2': array_2.tolist()
 }
```

and then try to dump it as a json:

```
import json

with open('json_data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_data, fp)
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: i can only make it work with `with open('json_data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_data, fp)`

Comment: @smvpfm: `json.dumps()` dumps to a string. Use `json.dump()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way of doing this is:

```
import json
with open("file.json", "wb") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work:
TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Comment: You need to deal with ndarray first. It's an unique data type

Answer (score 0):

First correct your data.
Correct data:
json_data = {
    'array_1': array_1,
    'array_2': array_2
 }

There is a extra ',' at the end of the line (array_2). That is the reason you are getting JSON serialization issue.