# How to store a dictionary in a file (Python)

Tags: python

I am new to python and I wanted to know if there is any way that I can store a dictionary in a file without using any module?
Example of Dictionary -

```
credentials = {
  "username" : "ABC",
  "email"    : "abc@email.com",
  "password" : "abc123@#"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "without using any module?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [saving dictionary into json python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253036/saving-dictionary-into-json-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `json` format

```py
import json
credentials = {
  "username" : "ABC",
  "email"    : "abc@email.com",
  "password" : "abc123@#"
}

with open("creds.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(credentials, outfile)
```

without Any module

```py
credentials = {
  "username" : "ABC",
  "email"    : "abc@email.com",
  "password" : "abc123@#"
}

with open("creds.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(credentials))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, the simplest way is just calling [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-str) on it:

```py
with open("out.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(<dict>))
```

Though it's probably not the smartest way to do it since you'll need to retrieve it back and then the problem might occur.

Instead perhaps use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dumps) (or [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dump) if you prefer using file descriptor), or [serialize it to XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) (manually since there's no simple "dumps()" as for json) or [`pickle.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps).

To retrieve the value back then use:

- [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#literal_eval) for `str()` (may break)
- [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.loads)/[`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.load) for JSON
- [`xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) for XML
- [`picke.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads)/[`picke.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) for binary pickle format

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

credentials = {
  "username" : "ABC",
  "email"    : "abc@email.com",
  "password" : "abc123@#"
}

for c in credentials:
    file_data = credentials.items()
file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.txt')

with open(f'{file_name}.txt', 'w') as write_file:
    write_file.write(str(file_data))
```